# Rails 3 remove item from existing array without another sql call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So this below has always worked for me, but now I need to remove some of the items to get true cost and true sale price.  I need to remove all items from this sum that has a parent_id of nil.  How can I do this without making another sql query?

```
def total_price
  # convert to array so it doesn't try to do sum on database directly
  items.to_a.sum(&:full_price)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
items.to_a.reject{|item|item.parent_id.nil?}.sum(&:full_price)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use select/reject method on array.

Comment: Why copypaste ruby tutorials? These are basics.